# Pine Script Strategy - How to trigger entry when *price* (not close) crosses a certain value? Currently entering trade one candle too late

Tags: pine-script

Just playing around, learning how to write strategies. The one I'm trying right now is (pseudo-code)...

```
if(previousCandle == red 
   ... AND previousCandle.high >= sma
   ... AND previousCandle.low <= sma 
   ... AND currentPrice > previousCandle.high)
    
    enter trade
```

What I have in Pine Script is...

```
redTouch = close < open and high >= ma and low <= ma

longCond = redTouch[1] and close > high[1]

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = longCond)
```

The `redTouch` candles are all identified correctly (checked previously using BG colors), but for the `longCond` I don't want `close > high[1]`, because that enters the trade only on the next candle (and too late).

The following screenshot shows where the trade is currently being entered (blue line on red candle), and where I'd like it to trigger/enter (yellow line on green candle).

[image: Late and desired trades]

How do I change `close > high[1]` to `price > high[1]` or a similar intra-candle crossover trigger? Or can you only enter trades in the *next* candle in Pine Script?

Comment: About tradingview's execution model - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html

Comment: This article might also be helpful - https://backtest-rookies.com/2017/11/15/backtesting-101-trades-delayed/

Comment: @e2e4 Thanks for the links. By all accounts it seems that backtesting only uses full candles for the period length. Looks like I'll have to mix and match period lengths to trick it into working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to do a few things to get the behavior you're looking for.

1. Add `process_orders_on_close=true` to your `strategy` declaration statement to get the Strategy tester to process on the bar that triggers the condition instead of the next bar's open.
2. Store the price you want to enter in a variable, maybe `high[1]+somenumber`
3. Add `limit=YourEntryPriceVariable` to your `strategy.entry` statement

This will create a limit order to enter at the price you specify on the bar that it happens.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I've moved on from that strategy for now, and so I don't have it coded up to test at the moment. I'm having some issues with my exits though, if you wanted to take a look at my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838172/pine-script-strategy-set-exit-limit-stop-based-on-atr-at-entry). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to enter an order in a more realtime like way and not wait until next bar is to create a stop entry before your conditions are met.  This may not work for all situations but was useful for me.

- add the condition you want before the stop should be entered / updated.
- Check if you are in a position (optional)
- I use a time value so I can limit my back test window

```
    if isLong() == false and inTradeWindow and high[1] < mid[1]
        strategy.entry("buy stop", strategy.long, 1, stop = mid)
```